# jQuery countdown current date to end date

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-countdown

I am using this plugin : http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html
I want to put countdown script code in php .
I have a php echo value like `2016-02-29` and this is countdown end date .
How to add this value to this countdown plugin to start a countdown from current date to end date?

Comment: and where is the code that "you're" using and where does php come into play here?

Comment: see update. i want to put this code in php @Fred-ii-

Comment: Somebody help..............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the plugin documentation

```
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: new Date(2016, 2-1, 29)});
```

For instance

```
<?php
$date = strtotime('2016-02-29');
?>
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: new Date(<?= (int)date('Y', $date) ?>, <?= (int)date('m', $date) ?>-1, <?= (int)date('d', $date) ?>)});
```

Comment: is there any way to put directly php end date code like `<?php echo $special_end; ?>` is `2016-02-29` ? @Jan